# In python test, self.assertRaisesRegex will give a "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred"

Tags: python-3.x

```
with self.assertRaisesRegex(MyException, "matched string"):
   function_that_will_raise()
```

If MyException thrown in the above code has a exception message that does not match "matched string", I get a

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

with self.assertRaisesRegex(
AssertionError: "matched string" does not match ....
```

Is this expected ? Why can't it be a normal test failure message (actual , expected, etc) and not something that indicates there's something wrong with my test code itself.